# modify current url

Tags: asp-classic

In classic asp, is there a way to add a parameter to a url of the called page?  So a request comes in from the client, the page is generated, and during the generation process the code in the page appends a random piece of data to the url of the page?

This is for an error page generated by iis, what I want is to append a random piece of data so that the client does not cache it.

I know there is an IIS setting that allows me to stop caching which is being used but I was wondering if i can do it via url manipulation.

Thanks

Comment: If I understand this correct, during the page load you want something added to the URL? Do you want it to show to the user or just something for page processing?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your specific question is: No.  The URL is "owned" by the client making the request, there is no way from the server side to modify what URL the client thinks its fetching.

To acheive your goal of preventing caching use:

```
 <%
    Response.Expires = -1
    Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
 %>
```

This simply informs the client not to cache the response or more specifically not to re-use the response without re-requesting the url from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should append a random value to the URL before you send the user to the error page, not after.  that will keep it from returning a cached response.